# Block collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

another question, my player is a square, and when he hits this pressure plate for example, this happen: https://i.gyazo.com/7866da3f8371aee6c319fd447f1bee95.gif

My code in the pressure plate object is this:

```
    Animator pressionar;
    public Transform playerCheck;
    public LayerMask playerLayer;
    public bool pressured = false;

    void Start () {
        pressionar = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update () {

        pressionar.SetBool("Pressionado", pressured);
        pressured = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerCheck.position, 0.15f, playerLayer);
    }
```

I tried changing to circle collision but didn't change nothing, thanks.

Comment: Sooooo what is your question? Lol

Comment: He "flip" when touch the pressure plate, i don't know how to solve this

Comment: Either put constrains on the rigidbody rotation or make the pressure plate a trigger, and on trigger enter, make it set a bool to the animator to change the animation to the down state.

Comment: Vitor if you want to include an image, click Edit on your question ... look for an use the handy "Image" button, you can show the image in the question

Comment: I personally think the block falling over is a fun effect. You don't think you could actually expand that to be a core puzzle-solving mechanic of the game, do you? =P

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible ways to solve this that I can think of.

First: Try locking the rotation of the square's z axis in the RigidBody2D.  It's within the Constraints section.

Second: Try creating a ramp for the square to slide onto the button.  You could do this using a Polygon Collider.  See link for details.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html

Third: Use a script to activate an OnCollisionEnter function that would place the square onto the button, or to push down the button, which would allow the cube to slide on.  See link for details.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Hopefully these resources can be of some help to you.  You can mix and match to try and find a method that gives you the best result.